# How to pass parameter to function in middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I wanted to pass a parameter to a middleware but I'm struggling on some points.

I have that function in the routes' handler:

```
router.get('/users', auth.required, userController.findAll);
```

Then it would go to the auth function which calls `getTokenFromHeaders`:

```
const auth = {
  required: jwt({
    secret: 'secret',
    userProperty: 'payload',
    getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
  }),
   ...
};
```

In `getTokenFromHeaders` function, the token is retrieved and checked, it looks like that:

```
const getTokenFromHeaders = (req) => {
...
   return token; // Or null in case it's not there or incorrect
```

So my goal would be to pass a parameter like that `auth.required('role')` to check the user's role inside `getTokenFromHeaders` function (defining more auth functions would be fine as well (auth.admin, auth.whatever, ...)

I already tried modifying it as the following:

```
const auth = {
  required: jwt({
    secret: 'secret',
    userProperty: 'payload',
    getToken: getTokenFromHeaders(req, res, role),
  }),
```

But it says that req and res is not defined.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Where will `'role'` originate from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get` method receives a path and 2 callbacks where first one is a middleware:

```
router.get('/users', auth, userController.findAll);
```

Middleware is like `findAll` function and is executed before:

```
var auth = function (req, res) {
    // Get token from header (http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get)
    var token = req.get("myToken");

    // TODO Validate token:
    var isValid = someFunction(token);
    if (!isValid) {
        // ************
        // TODO Check if user can access this resource
        // ************
        res.json("not authorized");
    }

    // Go to findAll (next callback)
};
```

I suggest you take at look in [docs](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html) specially in [app.use](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#app.use) to understand better how middleware works in express.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me to implement the solution and understand better how does middleware work :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that :

1) Call of request

```
app.use('/users', required);
```

2) Check authentification

```
const required = (req, res, next) => {
    const auth = {
        required: jwt({
            secret: 'secret',
            userProperty: 'payload',
            getToken: getTokenFromHeaders(req),
        }),
        ...
    };

    if (auth.required) next();
    else // error
}
```

3) Next step

```
router.get('/users', userController.findAll);
```

4) userController.findAll

userController.findAll will send the response with with the parameters recovered (req and res)